# Error en el metodo onItemSelected Spinner

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-spinner

Lo que intento hacer es que cuando el usuario complete el editText `codigoTxt` se llame la función `initViewModel` enviado los parametros del `codigoTxt` y un `0`, con esto se llena el spinner. Después cuando el usuario elija una opción del spinner quiero que se llame de nuevo `initViewModel` enviado los parametros del `codigoTxt` y **la opción seleccionada del spinner** con esto llena unos textview de acuerdo a la opción seleccionada.

El problema es que cuando el usuario elige un elemento el método `onItemSelected` se repite la cantidad de veces que los elementos que contiene el spinner.
Ejemplo si en el spinner hay 15 elementos y elijo la opcion 2 el metodo se repite 15 veces para la opción 2

```
 class Nuevo : Fragment(){

    private lateinit var viewModel: ViewModel
    private lateinit var codigoTxt:EditText
    private lateinit var mySpinner: Spinner
    var options: List<Int> = mutableListOf<Int>()
   
        
      override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nuevo, container, false)
      
 codigoTxt= view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.codigo)

  codigoTxt.addTextChangedListener(object:TextWatcher{
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?)  = Unit

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int)  = Unit

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
               try {
//aqui se llena el spinner cuando el usuario escribe algo en un EditText codigoTxt 
                   initViewModel(codigoTxt.text.toString(),0)
               }
               catch(e: Exception){

               }
            }
        })
                       
      mySpinner = view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.mySpinner)
        
      if(mySpinner!=null) {            
        mySpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        var count:Int=0
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
          TODO("not implemented") 
        }
        
         override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?,view: View?,position: Int,id: Long) {
          if (count >= 1) {
            var optionSelected=options.get(position)
            initViewModel(codigoTxt.text.toString(), optionSelected)   
          }
          count++
         }
        }
      }

val repository= Repository()
        val viewModelFactory= MainViewModelFactory(repository)
        viewModel= ViewModelProvider(this,viewModelFactory).get(ViewModel::class.java)
      return view
    }  

  private fun initViewModel(codigo:String,cod_Campo:Int){
    if(codigo.length==5)
        {
            viewModel.makeApiCallCampos(cod_Prod, cod_Campo)
            viewModel.myresponsecampos.observe(this, Observer { response ->
                response.clone().enqueue(object : Callback<List<MyDataItem>?> {

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MyDataItem>?>, t: Throwable) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Error: " + t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<MyDataItem>?>,response: Response<List<MyDataItem>?>) {
                        val responseBody: List<MyDataItem>? = response.body()
                        if (responseBody != null)
                        {
                            if(codigo.length==5 && cod_Campo==0) {
                                options = mutableListOf<Int>()
                                for (x in responseBody) {
                                    nombreTxt.setText(x.nombre)
                                    options += x.cod_Campo
                                }

                                val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
                                    activity!!,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                    options
                                )
                                mySpinner.adapter = adapter
                                optionSelected = adapter.getItem(0)!!
                            }

                            else{
                                for (x in responseBody)
                                {
                                    telefonoTxt.setText(x.telefono)
                                    localidadTxt.setText(x.ubicacion)
                                    tipoTxt.setText(x.tipo)
                                    productoTxt.setText(x.producto)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        }
        else {
            codigoTxt.setError("El código debe ser de 5 digitos, rellene con 0 al principio")
            codigoTxt.requestFocus()
        }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
class ViewModel (private val repository: Repository): ViewModel() {

val myresponsecampos:MutableLiveData<Call<List<MyDataItem>>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun makeApiCall(codigo: String, cod_Campo: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response= repository.getCampos(codigo, cod_Campo)
            myresponse.value=response
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Lee cómo crear un [mre]. Si completas tu pregunta puedo escribir una buena respuesta

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem ya lo hizo ^_^

Comment: @Christian te parece que el ejemplo es completo y verificable? No muestra como carga los datos al spinner ni como llena la variable `options`. Dice que `onItemSelected` se ejecuta 15 veces pero para que eso pase tendría que cambiar la selección programáticamente y no vemos ningún código que haga eso. Voto por cerrar la pregunta porque el problema no se puede reproducir. Todo lo que podemos decir es que `initViewModel` hace que `onItemSelected` sea infinitamente recursivo por lo que en algún punto `position` deja de ser un índice válido para `options.get(position)`

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem yo no sé mucho de kotlin, pensé que con el código añadido era más entendible el problema, yo solo avisé. Solo un experto o alguien que conozca bien el lenguaje podrá decidir si es suficiente o no, en este caso no lo fue. Igual, muy bien hecho en dejar el comentario diciendo el por qué.

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem ya he modificado la pregunta

Comment: Veo que hay problemas de lógica. Puedes dar un poco de contexto sobre lo que intentas hacer? Y sería bueno que agregues el viewModel pero no lo pongas como snippet de js.

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem  ya he modificado la pregunta

Comment: No me queda claro que quieres que suceda cuando selecionas una opción del spinner.  La explicación que falta es a nivel usuario. Los parámetros y funciones que se llaman podemos verlos en el código. Actualmente lo que haces cuando el usuario selecciona una opción es cambiar todas la opciones de ese mismo spinner, lo que no tiene sentido para mí. No será que quieres llenar otro spinner que dependa del anterior?

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem he modificado la pregunta, espero sea mas claro. He modificado el código también pero el problema persiste

Comment: Mucho mejor! Casi es una pregunta bien formulada. Podría responder pero aún hay cosas que no tienen sentido para mi. `responseBody` contiene un elemento o varios? Si esperas que tenga 1, por qué lo recorres con un `for`? Que pretendes cuando llamas, por ejemplo, `nombreTxt.setText(x.nombre)` dentro del `for`? Acaso quieres concatenar todos los nombres recibidos? Por qué la obsesión de poner el código de tu pregunta como ejecutable? De cualquier forma un `setText()` no tiene sentido dentro de un `for`.

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem responseBody contiene varios elementos cuando llena el spinner, y uno cuando concateno todos los nombres recibidos, nombreTxt.setText(x.nombre) es para poner los resultado recibidos en los TextView. He usado un for para poder sacar los elementos de responseBody

Comment: Poner una recompensa no mejora la calidad de tu pregunta. Escribiré una respuesta pero por la falta de información no podré hacerla muy completa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entre los muchos errores que hay en tu código, uno de los mas graves está en el método `initViewModel`. Aparte de estar muy mal nombrado, cada vez que lo llamas está añadiendo un nuevo observer al liveData `myresponsecampos`

```
viewModel.myresponsecampos.observe(this, Observer {...})
```

La primera vez lo llamas con el código `0` y se crea un `Observer` dentro del cual `cod_Campo` siempre va a valer `0` porque ese es el valor que tenía en el momento en que lo creaste.
Luego seleccionas un item del spinner y se vuelve a llamar el método. Ahora se crea otro observer y ambos reacionan al cambio en `myresponsecampos`. Es decir que todo el código dentro de `Observer { }` se ejecutará 2 veces, una por el observer donde `cod_Campo` vale 0 y otra por el nuevo observer.

El primer observer seguirá creando innecesariamente una nueva lista de opciones y un nuevo adapter cada vez que observe un cambio en el LiveData. Al asignarle este nuevo adapter al spinner, el item seleccionado cambia y entonces se ejecuta `onItemSelected`, quien llama a `initViewModel`. Entonces se crea otro observer y se sigue repitiendo el ciclo hasta que el dispositivo se queda sin memoria o tu app se cierra por algún otro motivo provocado por el bucle infinito.

La solución es dejar de crear objetos innecesarios. Lo primero es tener un solo observer observando el liveData. Para eso puedes mover esta parte al `onCreateView`

```
viewModel.myresponsecampos.observe(this, Observer {...})
```

Tu spinner solamente necesita un adapter así que tampoco tiene sentido crear más. Por ejemplo podrías almacenarlo en una propiedad

```
private val adapter by lazy {
    ArrayAdapter(requireActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mutableListOf<Int>())
}
```

Ese adapter debes asignarlo al spinner durante el `onCreateView`

```
mySpinner.adapter = adapter
```

Luego en el `onResponse`, elimina el código para crear otro adapter y simplemente cambia los elementos del adapter existente

```
adapter.clear()
adapter.addAll(responseBody.map{ it.cod_Campo })
```

De esta forma `onItemSelected` no se ejecuta y por lo tanto no entras en el bucle infinito.

La variable `options` también es innecesaria porque podrías reemplazar `options.get(position)` por `adapter.getItem(position)`.